# New UNIX User- need help troubleshooting error 0403-057

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, aix

I am new to UNIX and can not execute some very simple code. I am trying to execute a KornShell (ksh) command and receive an error :

```
0403-057 Syntax error at line 82 : `if' is not matched.
```

where line 82 is:

```
". /home/C_files/_bash.cfg"
```

I did not know that calling a config file qualifies as an "if" statement"

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 1. "0403-057" error msgs? Arg... AIX? Good luck. 2. error likely inside of file /home/C_files/_bash.cfg. 3. bash_cfg with ksh? There are occasional problems between bash and ksh syntax. Add `export PS4='${LINENO} >'` before line 82. Good luck!

Comment: 1) AIX 2) yeah, I am double checking now 3) can you give me some color/references on how/why problems exist between bash/ksh?

Comment: 3) Sorry that was my experience 5 yrs ago making a script that could run in Solaris ksh AND Cygwin bash. Pretty obscure stuff. Anything very fancy is suspect. But this may be a red-herring in your case. 4) 'if is not matched' is a pretty common error msg to get while developing code AND difficult to debug. The best I can offer is to take things apart, comment out logical blocks of code until you get no errors, then restore parts of the code until you find which block/line has the error in it.

Comment: You'd have to post the  SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) corresponding to your problem, which will no longer occur on line 82 but on line 2 (or maybe line 8).  Then maybe we can help.  Do not post 82 lines without a very convincing explanation of why the code cannot be reduced.

Comment: The error occurs from the second line of code. Lines 2 through 81 are comments describing the program. #!/usr/bin/ksh is the first line, and the second line is . /home/C_files/_bash.cfg

Comment: 5. Comment out line 82 and then rerun. Your script won't like all the unset variables that are the result, but thats a different error msg. 6. Temp Change top line of main script to `#!/usr/bin/ksh -n`. If you get no output, now you know there are no syntax issues in the current file. Remove the `-n`. Go to your cmd line, and just run just `. /home/C_files/_bash.cfg` by itself. Still get the error msg, right? Now you're sure the error is in that file. Divide and conquer as described in `4)` earlier. May take a while. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks- when I run . /home/C_files/_bash.cfg I get a command not found msg. I will double check the bash file.

Answer (score 0):

The sourcing of a file is running any code within that file. Even if it is supposed to be just a config file, you can still put all normal ksh commands inside it.

Posting the config file may lead to further enlightenment.